# Long Multiply C

Tags: c, multiplication, arbitrary-precision

I'm trying to implement the long multiply method (grade school method) in C. I need to write my program in base 2^32. I'm not sure how to even start. I have the algorithm that I want to use here:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   carry = 0;
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      product = a[i] * b[j] + result[i + j] + carry;
      result[i + j] = p % base;
      carry = floor(product / base);
   }
   result[i + n] = carry;
}
```

Any hints are appreciated. I just can't come up with a good idea.

Comment: What do you mean by base 2^32?

Comment: Basically, instead of treating the number like you normally would in base 10. My numbers a and b are represented by arrays of "digits" which are 32 bit words. Each "digit" can be of the range 0 to 2^32 - 1 rather than 0 to 9 like in base 10.

Comment: I would say that all you need to do is look at how big each of your variables can be, and what the means for what data type to use.

Comment: It's also called as basecase multiplication, you might take a look at `mpz_mul` definition (and subsequent ones) from [mini-gmp source](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-6.0/file/2ff56d3c5dfe/mini-gmp/mini-gmp.c).

Comment: For this algorithm to work, your `product` variable needs to be larger than your base. (But on the plus side, if your `result` can only store up to `base` you don't need the modulo to store it.) Try this algorithm with a base number that you know -- say `10`.

Comment: [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is a popular algorithm.

Comment: Minor: 1) Initialize `result` elements to 0. 2) should not `result[i + n] = carry;` --> `result[i + j] = carry;`?  OR run loops `for (t = 0; t < n; t++)`  (drop the -1)

Comment: @chux Could you elaborate a bit on point number 2?

Comment: I'd expect the index to run from `0... n-1`.  Code above runs from `0... n-2`.  Notice last usage of `result[i + j] = p % base;` is `result[i + n-2] = p % base;`, but then `result[i + n] = carry;`.  What happened to `result[i + n-1] = carry;`?

Comment: Oh I see. It was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that I have 2 numbers with 'digits':

b_2 b_1 b_0

and:

a_1 a_0

to multiply these together we first multiply by all the 'b's by a_0. We then multiply all the 'b's by a_1 and move the result one place to the left (which is 32 bits) before adding the two results together.

To multiply by a_0 move a_0 into a 64bit variable then multiply by b_0. the bottom 32 bits is the bottom 32 bits of the  multiplication result c_0. the top 32 bits is the carry.

Next multiply a_0 by b_1 (again in 64 bits). Take bottom 32 bits of the result and add the carry this will make the next 32 bits of the result: 'c_1'. The top 32 bits is the next carry. Repeat this until you've multiplied by all the digits in b. The final carry is the top 32 bits of the result.

Then do the same for a_1. Once you have the result of the multiplication remember to add the extra 32bits at the end of the a_1 multiplication. Then add the result of the multiplication of a_1 and 1_0 together.

Comment: Given this is something we've all learned to do at school it's a surprisingly difficult one to explain when applied to a different base! (I've done my best but not sure how clear it is).

Comment: This is great stuff. This along the lines of what I was thinking, but I couldn't think about it very clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The main "trick" is to find a way to multiple two 32-bit numbers and get either a 64-bit number or two 32-bit numbers which are the high- and low-halves. The high-half is the carry, and the low-half is the result (mode 2^32). On x86 machines there is an assembly language instruction that does exactly that, but to do it in straight C/C++ you will need to cast the multiplicands to some 64-bit type before multiplying, and then use shifts and masks to separate the high- and low-halves.

Answer (score 2):

In order to multiple with digits in `base`, you need native multiply and add instructions that can deal with two digits in `base`.  So if `base` is 2<sup>32</sup>, you'll need a 64 bit type, as well as a 32 bit type.

With that, you end up with code that looks like:

```
/* multiply two n-word numbers, giving a 2n-word result */
void multiply(uint32_t *result, uint32_t *a, uint32_t* b, int n) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
        result[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uint32_t carry = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            uint64_t product = (uint64_t)a[i] * b[j] + result[i + j] + carry;
            result[i + j] = product & 0xffffffff;
            carry = product >> 32; }
        result[i+n] = carry; }
}
```

essentially the same code you have, with a cast to make sure it uses the right type.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not following the line that says:                result[i + j] = product & 0xffffffff

Comment: Minor points 1) drop `int i, j;` 2) Consider `size_t` for `n,i,j` 3) `const uint32_t *a, const uint32_t* b`.

Comment: @Chaz -- this pulls out just the lowest 32 bits of `product` -- equivalent to mod 2**32 (your `p % base` line)